# Remote management on OSX platform over the internet (dynamic ip)

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I've installed a Mac into my parents' house. They're not tech people and I'll need to take care of all the system update/ software update, and possibly some remote assistance to them (screen sharing). I live in another country so this needs to be carried on over the internet.

I'm wondering what's the best option I have considering the following requirements:

- I'm on Mac as well, so it doesn't need to be cross platform
- Both me and them have dynamic IPs, I need to be able to connect to them without knowing their IP address
- Ideally they'll use a non admin account with limited rights, but I'd like to remote login as administrator to perform administrative tasks.
- It might be a paid service but it shouldn't be too expensive (10 euro/month)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO as it's not about programming.

Comment: I agree. I just don't know how to close it